# How to deal with data frame column headers that have hyphens in them?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that was scraped from a webpage. Some of the column headers have hyphens in them (for example, ERA-), and it does not seem like dplyr allows me to deal with them.

I am trying to do this:

```
dataframe_new <- dataframe_old %>%
   transmute(ERA_minus = ERA-)
```

but I keep getting `Error: unexpected ')' in:`

I'm pretty new to R, so what's the best way to deal with something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use backquotes for those columns

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe_old %>%
   transmute(ERA_minus = `ERA-`)
```

Comment: Well, that was much easier than I anticipated! Thank you!